# Run a bash linux command for a specified time

Tags: linux, bash, time, timeout

Is there a way in linux please to execute a command just a certain duration of time like 10 minutes ?

I wanna make a capture with: `airodump-ng -w $CAPT_DEST $mon`
But i just want it to last 10 minutes and then the command stops automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you are looking for is `timeout`:

```
timeout 600 airodump-ng -w "$CAPT_DEST" "$mon"
```

See `man timeout` for more information.

Comment: Thanks you ! And if i want to recall it back ?

Comment: @voguendi "recall it back"?

Comment: I want that after the end of my script it is recalled back ? I have a script in which this command is in the middle. So after 10 min it will be stopped and the end of the script will be executed. And then i want to recall it back and start my script from this line.

Comment: What does "recalled back" mean?

Comment: To restart my script but from this line !

Comment: If you want to call it indefinitely, you can do something like `while true; do command; done`. But I'm not sure if I understand your question.

Comment: Yeah that's what i was thinking about ! Thanks!